# twitter API fetching tweets after since id

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, twitter, twitter4j

I'm trying to process tweets through twitter4j. As described here https://dev.twitter.com/docs/working-with-timelines, i have sent my first request with only parameter "count" to retrieve first 100 tweets according my criteria. The subsequent requests should have since_id parameter set with the latest tweet id i retrieved from previous call, so that it will return latest tweets after the given since_id. But what i understand here is, when we send since_id, if there are 200 new tweets are available after that id, the latest 100 will be returned, so i'm going to miss the 100 in between. How should i set the request parameters, so that i can retrieve X amount of tweets from the given since_id? I need to retrieve 100 tweets after the last retrieved tweet id from every call.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can retrieve it, check out https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/user_timeline
You have the max_id, since_id and count options that can help you out get the required result.
Let's say the last tweet you got has an ID=X. Save the result somewhere so that next time you specify the since_id as X and you get all the tweets that have an ID greater than this one.

Comment: This should be marked as best answer. Exactly, you should retrieve all tweets information into local database initially before any future analysis. On another word, analysis on tweets should be executed locally rather than requesting twitter api in realtime.